# Google Colab stopped executing, what can I do to keep this project?

Tags: google-colaboratory

Error
Failed to execute cell. Could not send execute message to runtime: Error: Not connected to a runtime.
Not connected to a runtime.
Error: Not connected to a runtime.
    at GW (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20200305-085600-RC00_299114455:3833:412)
    at HW (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20200305-085600-RC00_299114455:2530:111)
    at https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20200305-085600-RC00_299114455:2545:280
    at e.onFulfilled (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20200305-085600-RC00_299114455:270:216)
    at lk (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20200305-085600-RC00_299114455:274:306)
    at hk (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20200305-085600-RC00_299114455:274:164)
    at Pj.executeCallbacks_ (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20200305-085600-RC00_299114455:273:359)
    at Ji (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary.js?vrz=colab-20200305-085600-RC00_299114455:234:551)

Comment: What steps do you take that cause this error? As is, there's not enough information in the question to reproduce this failure.

Comment: Hey Bob
Thanks for your attention, the problem solved. I have removed some of my chrome extensions.